# A simple application of todo not adding input value to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Every time my controller adds new input on view but blank, I want it should add new input with entered value.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>My todos</h2>

    <form ng-submit="addTodo()" role="form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo" value="Something" placeholder="Add">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

    <p class="form-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo" class="form-control">
    </p>

</div>

The above code has separate temple main.html and calling that code inside index.html 

     <div ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

then whenever I add new todo, its add input blank, and add null value inside todos array list.
   but when loading template without using ng-include its work fine.

```
angular.module('mymailApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.todos = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'];

    $scope.addTodo = function(){
        $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
        $scope.todo = "";
    };

  }]);
```

Comment: it looks fine, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @JoaoLeal see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2bvx2oh/7/

Comment: @Mukesh, your Fiddle isn't working. See http://plnkr.co/edit/Erw2BXZV2Xr1mjekuRz3. This is working fine. Is your problem that you want to ignore empty todos?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the console, you'll see that your Fiddle isn't loading the angular module.

Comment: @user125661 actually problem is exists when i include html using ng-include="views/main.html", my main consists my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i solved the issue moving controller call to "main.html" template, as ng-include template doesnt call the ng-controller directly, it should use either $routeProvider or controller should be call inside the template

modified code looks something like that:

ng-controller="MainCtrl" moves inside main.html

Answer (score 0):

Change "onDomReady" to "no wrap - in head" in the left panel "Frameworks & Extensions" panel

Also, in your module call, you want to pass a second parameter, an array containing all of your module's dependencies.  In your case, an empty array `[]`

```
angular.module('mymailApp',[]).controller(...)
```

Without the second parameter, it assumes you are trying to extend an existing module, not define a new one.

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2bvx2oh/11/

Comment: if i load template using ng-include="'views/main.html'" and add todo its return null value

Comment: <div ng-include="'views/main.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div> , my main.html contains <div class="container">
    <h2>My todos</h2>

    <form ng-submit="addTodo()" role="form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo" value="Something" placeholder="Add">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    {{todos}}
    <ul class="form-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <li>
            <input type="text" ng-model="todo" class="form-control">
            <button ng-click="removeTodo($index)"></button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

rest of the controller logic same

Comment: Can you modify your question to include the additional information?  Or create a new question for this new problem.